# Create a random 3D asteroid

Tags: popularity-contest, graphical-output

Imagine you are working on a 3D adaptation of the classical video game [Asteroids](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asteroids_%28video_game%29). Your task is to write an algorithm that can create a random 3D asteroid.

This is a popularity contest, not code golf. Write nice code and create interesting results. Add other cool features if you want.

Rules:

- Your algorithm must actually create the model, not just load it from an external source or similar.
- The results must be (pseudo-)random. Running the algorithm several times must create different results.
- Real-time capability is desirable, but not necessary.
- Low or high polygon count? Realistic or stylized? You decide...
- The output must be a [mesh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon_mesh), either in memory or as a file such as [Wavefront OBJ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file). In either case you need to render it in some way.
- Explain your algorithm, so that everybody can learn from it.
- Show some images of your results.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

## Blender + Python

Blender's built-in Python scripting is perfect for this sort of thing.

[image: GIF animation of a spinning asteroid]

Open a Python console and paste in the following:

```
import bpy
import random

def asteroid():
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_ico_sphere_add()
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
    bpy.ops.mesh.faces_shade_smooth()
    bpy.ops.mesh.select_mode(type='VERT')
    bpy.ops.mesh.select_random()
    bpy.ops.transform.resize(value=(random.uniform(1.1,1.4),random.uniform(1.1,1.4),random.uniform(1.1,1.4)))
    bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='SELECT')
    bpy.ops.mesh.subdivide(smoothness=1)
    bpy.ops.mesh.select_random()
    bpy.ops.transform.resize(value=(random.uniform(1.05,1.15),random.uniform(1.05,1.15),random.uniform(1.05,1.15)))
    bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='SELECT')
    bpy.ops.mesh.subdivide(smoothness=1)
    bpy.ops.mesh.select_random()
    bpy.ops.transform.resize(value=(random.uniform(0.92,1.05),random.uniform(0.92,1.05),random.uniform(0.92,1.05)))
    bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='SELECT')
    bpy.ops.mesh.subdivide(smoothness=1)
    stretch = random.uniform(0.9,1.5)
    bpy.ops.transform.resize(value=(stretch,1,1))
    bpy.ops.transform.rotate(value=(random.uniform(-1.57,1.57)), axis=(random.uniform(-1.57,1.57),random.uniform(-1.57,1.57),random.uniform(-1.57,1.57)))
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')

asteroid()
```

An asteroid will then be created at the position of your 3D cursor:

[image: Wireframe render of asteroid 3D model]

Want another asteroid? Move the 3D cursor somewhere else and then type `asteroid()` into the Python console again (or just <kbd>↑</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> to repeat the last line entered).

To make it look more like a piece of space rock and less like a blob of plastic, you need to apply a suitable material. The following procedural material works quite well. I used a diffuse colour of `#635C5B`, and `#8D887F` in the marble texture.

[image: Space rock material settings]

**How it works:**

1. Start by creating a simple icosahedron (`bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_ico_sphere_add()`).
2. Enter edit mode (`bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')`) and apply smooth shading so that the individual facets blend into one another (`bpy.ops.mesh.faces_shade_smooth()`).
3. Select a random subset of the object's vertices (`bpy.ops.mesh.select_random()`).
4. Scale them randomly in the X, Y and Z directions (`bpy.ops.transform.resize()`).
5. Select the whole object (`bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='SELECT')`) and apply smooth subdivision to add new vertices by interpolating smoothly across the deformed object (`bpy.ops.mesh.subdivide(smoothness=1)`).
6. (Repeat steps 3–5 a couple more times.)
7. Stretch the object in the X direction to make it a bit less spherical (`bpy.ops.transform.resize(value=(stretch,1,1))`)
8. Apply a random rotation transform (`bpy.ops.transform.rotate()`)
9. Finally, exit edit mode and leave the object selected (`bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')`).

**More examples:**

[image: Asteroid 1][image: Asteroid 2][image: Asteroid 3][image: Asteroid 4]

Comment: Holy Bajeezus! .

Comment: Wow that is great!